# MongoDb munging HTML entities like "&reg;" into "&amp;reg;" on save() from PHP

Tags: html, mongodb, character, html-entities

On MongoDb 2.0.6, running on 64 bit, with PHP 5.4 with the official driver. MongoDb save() of

```
&reg;
```

is stored as

```
&amp;reg;
```

Mongo apparently munges all & into & amp; thus breaking html entities when output to the browser again! Storing "Bose®" works fine, it is stored as "Bose®". What is going on here? I want MongoDb to stop altering my data. I deliberatly store HTML entities like

```
&reg;
```

to avoid such issues, but MongoDb turns it into

```
&amp;&reg;
```

on save() through PHP? Is this a bug or a "feature"?

Currently, I have to do a html_entity_decode() all my strings/data before save() to MongoDb...

Comment: Care to share your PHP code? It seems somewhat *presumptuous* to *presuppose* that "MongoDB" is causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is **NOT** munging the data in this way.  There is something else in your application that's munging the data.

Here is a simple test program:

```
<?php

$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->test;
$collection = $db->tb;

$collection->drop();
$collection->save( array( 'name' => ">>&reg;<<" ) ) ; 
$cursor = $collection->find();

foreach ($cursor as $doc) 
    print(" {$doc['name']} \n");

?>
```

When run, it produces the following output:

```
 >>&reg;<<
```

Clearly, something else in your toolchain is performing the HTML encoding.

Comment: MongoDb is natively UTF-8 if I'm not mistaken. The problem was probably caused by mixed encoding of the source data. So for that matter, you're right that MongoDb does not munge data, it's a problem with source data encoding.

Comment: MongoDB **is** natively UTF-8.  The OP was making a different claim: that an ASCII-only string that contained an HTML entity was being HTML-encoded.  MongoDB does ***NOT*** do this -- the problem was clearly elsewhere in their code.